# relationship between coefficients of a differential equation when product of solutions is constant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $ y_1 y_2 $ is the product of the two solutions of the differential equation $ y'' + p_1 y' + p_2y = 0 $ and it is a constant. How can the requirement for this be $2p_1p_2 + p_2' = 0$? I have tried several manipulations but cannot get the desired requirement. Any hints?

Thanks

Comment: You didn't try enough. You should use the fact that constants have a zero derivative, differentiating over and over again, and using the differential equation to always get expressions involving only $y_1,y_2$ and their first derivatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $y_1 y_2 = C \neq 0$. Differentiate once:
$$y'_1 y_2 + y_1 y'_2 = 0. $$
Differentiate again:
$$y''_1 y_2 + 2y'_1y'_2 + y_1 y''_2 = 0. $$
Substitute the differential equation:
$$2y'_1 y'_2 = p_1 y'_1 y_2 + p_2 y_1 y_2 + p_1 y_1 y'_2 + p_2 y_1 y_2 = 2Cp_2. $$
Differentiate this:
$$2y''_1 y'_2 + 2y'_1 y''_2 = 2Cp'_2. $$
Substitute the differential equation:
$$0 = 2Cp'_2 + 2p_1y'_1y'_2 + 2p_2y_1y'_2 + 2p_1y'_1y'_2 + 2p_2y'_1y_2 =
2Cp'_2 + 4p_1y'_1y'_2 = 2Cp'_2 + 4Cp_1p_2. $$
Since $C \neq 0$, we deduce that
$$ p'_2 + 2p_1 p_2 = 0. $$